# does angular have forwardRef for component?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have `login-status` component that belong to `AuthModule`.

I also have `toolbar` component inside `shell` component in `CoreModule`.

My app component only contains `shell` component. (the `shell` is render the `toolbar`).

Every module in my application is depent on `CoreModule` because `CoreModule` export other modules and core components that can be use in my features modules like `AuthModule`.

This mean in AuthModule I import CoreModule.

Well the problem is in Toolbar component I need to display the login-status component. 
So I add login-status component to `exports` in `AuthModule` and I import the `AuthModule` in `CoreModule`.

The problem is cause circular dependency in my app.

I think I organized it by reason:

- login-status belong to AuthModule
- toolbar and shell and router-outlet belong to CoreModule.
- The app.component render the shell component.

There is something like `forwardRef` for component that tell angular to handle this circular dependency? or any nice idea how to fix that?

Comment: Does the `login-status` comp only displays the current status? If yes, then I don't think you need a comp for that, so you might use a singleton service.

Comment: `login-status` only displays the current status. but it have logic what to display.. menu with items base if I login or not. so I think the component still belong to auth module